# SQL Server Join Queries using Rank and Partition

Tags: sql-server, rank, partition

I want one table of the highest BID and lowest ASK (price) for each EntityCode in the db.

The following two sets of code return two result sets I but cannot yet find/figure out how to join them:

Get highest Bid

```
(SELECT *   FROM    
   (SELECT 
        Contracts.Orders2Buy.EntityCode,
        Contracts.Orders2Buy.Bid,       
        Contracts.Orders2Buy.NumContractsStillAvailable,
        Contracts.Orders2Buy.TimePlaced,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityCode  
               ORDER BY Contracts.Orders2Buy.Bid DESC, 
               Contracts.Orders2Buy.TimePlaced DESC) AS Rank
    FROM
        Contracts.Orders2Buy
    WHERE
        Contracts.Orders2Buy.NumContractsStillAvailable > 0) AS temp
WHERE temp.Rank = 1)
```

Get Lowest Ask

```
(SELECT *   FROM    
(   SELECT 
        Contracts.Orders2Sell.EntityCode,
        Contracts.Orders2Sell.Ask,          
        Contracts.Orders2Sell.NumContractsStillAvailable AS AskVolume,
        Contracts.Orders2Sell.TimePlaced,
        RANK () OVER (  PARTITION BY EntityCode     
                ORDER BY    Contracts.Orders2Sell.Ask ASC, 
                Contracts.Orders2Sell.TimePlaced DESC) AS Rank
    FROM
        Contracts.Orders2Sell
    WHERE
        Contracts.Orders2Sell.NumContractsStillAvailable > 0) AS temp2
WHERE temp2.Rank = 1)
```

Comment: This post went from cte vs table variable performance to something about sql server cost vs web server cost?

Comment: My advice 1) ask a specific question.  2) post your relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UNION, use JOIN to combine three result sets into one result.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    highestBid hb
        JOIN lowestAsk la ON hb.stock_symbol = la.stock_symbol
        JOIN mostRecent mr ON la.stock_symbol = mr.stock_symbol
```

put the fields you need from each set in place of `*`

Answer (score 0):

What I sought to accomplish requires joining the code blocks above as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 

      (Code block 1) t1

INNER JOIN

      (Code block 2) t2

ON t1.EntityCode = t2.EntityCode
```